# LEFT JOIN does not output desired result

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have here my sample query using codeigniter. I'm using this to get data satisfying my where condition.

MODEL:

```
    function quarterly1_sales($year_date, $q1_start){
     $where = array(
     'status'   => 'purchased',
     'payment.paymentdate >=' => $q1_start,
     'payment.paymentdate <=' => 'DATE_ADD('.$q1_start.',INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)');
    return $this->db
    ->select('COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count')
    ->select('product_key.client_name, product_key.contact_email, product_key.status, product_key.id, payment.paymentdate, (payment.id) as pid,payment.subscription_type')
    ->from('product_key')
    ->where($where)
    ->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'left outer')
    ->group_by('product_key.id')
    ->get()
    ->result(); 
    }
```

CONTROLLER:

```
if($data['filter'] == 'quarterly'){
//1st quarter of the year
    @$q1_start = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(date($year_date).'-01-01'));
$data['quarterly1_sales'] = $this->basemodel->quarterly1_sales($year_date, $q1_start);
$this->load->view('sales', $data);          
}
```

VIEW:

```
if($filter == 'quarterly'){
    $title = "Quarterly Sales Summary for ".$date_year;

    echo "<br /><strong>".$title."</strong></div>
        </tr>"<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Email Address</th>
    <th>Payment Date</th>
    <th>Subtotal Amount</th>
```

";

```
    foreach ($quarterly1_sales as $quarter1) :

        echo $client_name = $quarter1->client_name;
        echo $paymentdate = $quarter1->paymentdate;
        echo $email = $quarter1->contact_email;
        echo $recount= $quarter1->rec_count;
        echo $sum_amount = $recount * 588;
    if($recount == 0){
        $display = "display:none;";
    }else{
        $display = "";
    }
```

endforeach;

My problem is, there shouldn't be any result since my data starts with 2012 and 2013 yet it outputs everything.
Hope someone could help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: @AldiUnanto: Nothing. It shows all my data.

Comment: Try taking `'DATE_ADD(2010-01-01,INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)'` out of the single quotes, MySQL might be evaluating that literally instead of actually executing the function.

Comment: @BadWolf: `2010-01-01` is dynamic so I can't do that.

Comment: I think the `<=` is doing the conflict.

Comment: @Prix to the OP with their ALL CAPS QUESTION TITLE!

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr hope it looks ok now ;)

Comment: @Prix Yeah, but now my comment is less funny :P

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr don't worry I will laugh in secret about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codeigniter's active record class automagically escapes everything passed to the `where()` function. Because of this your call to the MySQL function `DATE_ADD()` is being passed in as a string and treated literally by MySQL instead of being evaluated. To fix this, move that where clause to a separate function call and set the third parameter to FALSE, turning off the escaping.

```
$where = array(
     'status'   => 'purchased',
     'payment.paymentdate >=' => $q1_start);
    return $this->db
    ->select('COUNT(payment.keyid) AS rec_count')
    ->select('product_key.client_name, product_key.contact_email, product_key.status, product_key.id, payment.paymentdate, (payment.id) as pid,payment.subscription_type')
    ->from('product_key')
    ->where($where)
    ->where('payment.paymentdate <=', 'DATE_ADD('.$this->db->escape($q1_start).',INTERVAL 1 QUARTER)', FALSE)
    ->join('payment', 'payment.keyid=product_key.id', 'left outer')
    ->group_by('product_key.id')
    ->get()
    ->result();
```